# what is Mylyn in eclipse ? Pydev plugin says Mylyn integration

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, mylyn

When i install some plugins, I used to see this term Mylyn Integration. what exactly is it ? I tried to add pydev plugin to my eclipse.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the homepage for Mylyn: http://eclipse.org/mylyn/

Here is a summary description (taken from that page):

> Mylyn is the *task and application lifecycle management (ALM) framework* for Eclipse. It provides:
>
> - **The revolutionary task-focused interface**
>
>   Realigns the IDE around tasks so that you see only the code that's relevant
> - **A task management tool for developers**
>
>   Averaging 1 million downloads/month, Mylyn is the most popular IDE tool for ALM
> - **A broad ecosystem of Agile and ALM integrations**
>
>   Dozens of extensions integrate Mylyn with ALM and developer collaboration tools

Hope that helps.